# Is this Borel summation true?

Tags: sequences-and-series, definite-integrals

I found this alternating series can be deformed:
$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^k\frac{(nk)!}{k!}=\sum_{k=0}
^\infty \frac{(-1)^k}{k!}\int_{0}^{\infty}x^{nk}e^{-x} \ dx \\ 
=\int_{0}^{\infty}\left[\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-x^n)^k}{k!}\right]e^{-x}dx=\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-x^n-x} \ dx 
$$
This expression have suggested that the series have Borel summation as below:
$$
\sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^k\frac{(2k)!}{k!}=\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-x^2-x} \ dx =0.54564\cdots  
$$
and
$$
\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \ \sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^k\frac{(nk)!}{k!}=\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty } \ \int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-x^n-x} \ dx =\frac{e-1}{e}  
$$
Are these true?

Comment: Since the inner series $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{\left(-x^n\right)^k}{k!}$ diverges for large $n$, exchanging the order of the series and the integral isn't valid.

Comment: It seems to be the Borel summation of the Gevrey-$(n-1)$ series $$
\sum\limits_{k = 0}^\infty  {( - 1)^k \frac{{(nk)!}}{{k!}}z^k } 
$$ at $z=1$.

Comment: Ignoring that neither side converges and exchanging formally, is that expression true?

Comment: I don't know this series.Thank you.